# Prevent <c-w>q to quit Vim when there is only one window left

Tags: quit, vim9, vim9script

I wish to close windows and wipe out the associated buffers with `<c-w>q` but at the same time I want to prevent to quit Vim when there is only one window left.

My attempt is as follows:

```
vim9script
def QuitWindow()
    # Close window and wipe buffer but prevent Vim to quit if one window is
    # left.
   if winnr('$') != 1
      quit
   endif
enddef

nnoremap <c-w>q <Cmd>call QuitWindow()<cr>
nnoremap <c-w><c-q> <Cmd>call QuitWindow()<cr>
```

but then `QuitWindow()` is correctly not recognised and I am not sure how to do for recognising a function when it is defined in `.vimrc` and is not defined as global.

Perhaps this is not the right direction for achieving my goal?

Comment: Simple. If you don't want Vim to quit when you press `<C-w>q` and there's only one window… don't press `<C-w>q` when there is only one window. Also, the RHS of a normal mode mapping is a normal mode macro: use `:call …` or `<Cmd>call …`.

Comment: Please re-read `:help <Cmd>`.

Comment: The first part of your comment is of no utility at all. The second part makes more sense and I realised that I missed a <Cmd> but then another problem arise and therefore I updated my question as the objective is not reached yet.

Comment: Again, `:help <Cmd>`.

Comment: `:h <Cmd>` - Part 1:
"The special text <Cmd> begins a "command mapping", it executes the command
directly without changing modes.  Where you might use ":...<CR>" in the
{rhs} of a mapping, you can instead use "<Cmd>...<CR>".
Example: >
 noremap x <Cmd>echo mode(1)<CR>
<"

Comment: `:h <Cmd>` - Part 2: "This is more flexible than `:<C-U>` in Visual and Operator-pending mode, or
`<C-O>:` in Insert mode, because the commands are executed directly in the
current mode, instead of always going to Normal mode.  Visual mode is
preserved, so tricks with |gv| are not needed.  Commands can be invoked
directly in Command-line mode (which would otherwise require timer hacks)."

Comment: `:h <Cmd>` - Part 3: "Example of using <Cmd> halfway Insert mode: >
 nnoremap <F3> aText <Cmd>echo mode(1)<CR> Added<Esc>

Unlike <expr> mappings, there are no special restrictions on the <Cmd>
command: it is executed as if an (unrestricted) |autocommand| was invoked."

Comment: Here is the `:h <Cmd>` of my `MacVim`. In which line I find the solution to my problem? Because I really cannot see it from `:h <Cmd>.`

Comment: Who said anything about finding a solution to your problem? The point was to make your example at least syntactically correct.

Comment: For a solution, how about scrolling a little bit downward to `:help <ScriptCmd>`?

Comment: Much better solution than "Simple. If you don't want Vim to quit when you press <C-w>q and there's only one window" or insisting on `:h <Cmd>`.

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of completeness and as requested by a user, here is the solution that I am currently using (based on a user comment):

```
vim9script
def QuitWindow()
    # Close window and wipe buffer but prevent Vim to quit if one window is
    # left.
   if winnr('$') != 1
      quit
   endif
enddef

nnoremap <c-w>q <ScriptCmd>call QuitWindow()<cr>
nnoremap <c-w><c-q> <ScriptCmd>call QuitWindow()<cr>
```

The trick was in using `:h <ScriptCmd>` that allow you to define mappings in the context of scripts.
Note that in my case a `QuitWindow()` has script scope.
Alternatively, I could have used a global scope for `QuitWindow()`, i.e. `g:QuitWindow()` but that would have polluted the global namespace.

Answer (score 1):

I would do:

```
vim9script

def g:QuitWindow()
    # Close window and wipe buffer but prevent Vim to quit if one window is
    # left.
   if winnr('$') != 1
      quit
   endif
enddef

nnoremap <c-w>q <Cmd>call g:QuitWindow()<CR>
```

Comment: That is what I was thinking to do, but I would avoid polluting the global namespace :) But perhaps it is the only way?

Comment: For the mapping to work they need a global function unless you put the function statements into the mapping.

Comment: `<ScriptCmd>`  is another solution (actually the one I prefer) as someone pointed out in another comment. Thanks for your effort anyways :)

Comment: You are welcome :-) Publish your solution. I'll be happy to read it.